# How to FluentBootstrap validation in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentbootstrap

Is it possible to use validation messages in [FluentBootstrap](http://fluentbootstrap.com/) on form element level?

When I use:

```
@using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Form().Begin())
{
    @form.InputFor(m => m.Name)
    @form.Submit()
}
```

There is no validation, except validation error class on input tag. I want to show validation message for `Name` property and `has-error` class on `form-group` container.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@form.ValidationSummary()` where you want the general validation summary to appear. There is an example of this as well as some other examples here: https://github.com/daveaglick/FluentBootstrap/blob/develop/FluentBootstrap.Tests.Web/Views/MvcTests/MvcForms.cshtml

Comment: This is summary. And what about form item level validation?

Comment: You mean validation for `Name` if there are any validation errors? That should work with what you have. For example, here's a validation errors getting set: https://github.com/daveaglick/FluentBootstrap/blob/develop/FluentBootstrap.Tests.Web/Controllers/MvcTestsController.cs#L32 and here's the test that shows it: https://github.com/daveaglick/FluentBootstrap/blob/develop/FluentBootstrap.Tests.Web/Views/MvcTests/MvcForms.cshtml#L32 Is it not working for you?

Comment: Yes, it works, but the class 'has-error' on field container ('form-group') is not set. Maybe I am just missing the concept of fluent bootstrap usage...

Answer (score 0):

If there is no particular reason to use `InpuFor` you can do the following.

```
@form.EditorFor(m => m.Name, addValidationMessage: true)
```

This will show what error message you put on your `Name` property's attribute. 
Such as

```
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="Cannot be longer than 50 character.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the base validation helper

```
@form.InputFor(m => m.Password, FormInputType.Password)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
```

I can set the type of the input unlike the case when I use `EditorFor`